# xcode 3.2.6 not creating ipa file

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am creating a ipa file in xcode 3.2.6 but its not creating when i build and archive the app it doent not ask for saving the file and stops the processing how to fix this and make ipa working.

Comment: Make sure it's building for an iOS device and not the simulator, I've done this before.

Comment: yes i am buidling for iOS device in xcode 3 but not working again

Comment: Hey. Have you considered to get XCode 4.3 ? API file generating is pretty simple with it.

Comment: in xcode 4.3 i creat ipa file but i have new mobile provison so i have added in that but it is not installed i think that's why i am tryiyon in 3.2.6 on macbok becuase profile is installed on it

Answer (score 0):

if id doesn't generate any error, then you may have more than one project files in your project. i.e. your project is combined. or you may have not selected any executeable for your project.

Comment: which problem is in your projct from the above ones?

Comment: My excuatable is also set and what do you mean by merged project

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Build a app. And you will get a .app

2) Open iTunes

3) Drag and drop a .app to the iTunes at left panel on top. For truely drop, you must see a Green "+" about cursor when you are draged a .app on panel.

4) iTunes will convert your .app to .ipa file

5) Look at Users/{you}/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications folder and find your IPA app file

Hope this helps you

Comment: first things ipa file is not creating then how can i drag and drop

Comment: @user1397714 drag and drop the .app file.

Comment: i am doing this way but there is no any folder like Mobile Applications inside iTunes

Comment: search "iTunes Media" in "iTunes" folder, and inside him a "Mobile Applications"

Comment: you see a other .ipa files? if see, then you can create your own .ipa file with iTunes. Try again a step 3. when you do a mouse click and drag on iTunes on left tab, you must see a GREEN "+", then do a mouse up